# Trailing slashes in app-router path throwing errors (Polymer)

Tags: polymer, web-component

My app-router is set up as follows:

```
<app-router id="router" mode="pushstate">
<app-route path="/:category" import="bower_components/my-elements/category-page.html"></app-route>
<app-route path="/product/:query" import="bower_components/my-elements/product-page.html"></app-route>
</app-router>
```

Navigation to my category page works fine. If I change the path in the URL to be a different category then the content updates accordingly.

However when trying to load the product page, my app gets stuck in an infinite loop. The console prints an `uncaught syntax error with unexpected token '<'` coming from platform.js repeatedly.

Now I have noticed that this only happens whenever the path includes a slash. If I change the path to be just "/product" then the page loads fine but as soon as a slash is added so that the path is "/product/:query" or even "/product/new" then page doesn't load. The syntax error is infinitely thrown along with `"Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html"` and `"Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html"`

If I change the path of product-page to "/product" then no issues but by adding a slash to any path even category-page, causes the error to occur.

Does anyone know what may be causing this?

EDIT: updated title to be relevant to issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue, and I just figured out it is because of relative paths.  If you change the imports in your template (as well as the app-route imports) to absolute paths, that should fix your problem.

Comment: Changing the relative paths to absolute paths fixed the issue.

Thanks a lot for the help.